# react project generating ._filename.jsx(javascript) each time I create a new file

Tags: reactjs

[image: package.json file][screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oyc0.png)I am currently working with React on vscode and keep getting extra binary files generated each time I create a new file. I have attached a screenshot above, does anyone know why this might be happening?

I tried deleting the files, no issues with my code but its just annoying to have to delete them manually.

**-what I want to achieve**: create filename.jsx files for components without the extra ._filename.jsx being generated.

Comment: where is the screenshot ? didn't getting what you want to achive and whats is the issue  can you give some more details

Comment: @Lucifer, just added more details.

Comment: acn you share you packge.json file where you have the script to start the or build the project